# Separate XML data with Import XML on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets to data pictured from https://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Kelvin-Gastelum-74700

The data output is contained in cell A1. What custom function would I need to separate the data into fields and records as it is displayed on the website?!

[Kelvin Gastelum Sherdog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNupp.png)
[image: Output]

I tried using a custom function without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=importhtml(url,"table",2)
```

you have 9 tables, so you can try `=importhtml(url,"table",1)` to `=importhtml(url,"table",9)`

[image]